# Overwriting data in form view

Tags: forms, ms-access

If I want to overwrite some data in a field/control box of form view of MS Access, I have to select the field, delete the existing data and then enter new data. In excel this is much easier as I have select to the cell and simply start typing. In case of SAP when I select a field the existing data gets highlighted and I simply start typing to overwrite existing data. Is there any shortcut option like this in MS Access form view?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the textbox, press `F8` once to highlight the word clicked, once more to highlight the entire content.

Or, for a specific textbox, use the Click event:

```vb
Private Sub YourTextbox_Click()

    With Me!YourTextbox
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't know about F8.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

TAB into the control (that's why setting up a good Tab Order is important)

or click on the control's label instead of into the control.